# System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Expecting element from namespace

Tags: c#, wcf, httpclient

for some reason I feel like this call to post isn't setup correctly meaning the message to me I think is saying the method in WCF isn't receiving an InventoryRequest object in the POST?

```
   var inventoryRequest = new InventoryRequest
    {
        memberID = "1",
        Inventories = _inventories.ToArray()
    };


    //Act
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/Inventory");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        inventoryResponse = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("", inventoryRequest).Result.Content.ReadAsAsync<InventoryResponse>();
    }
```

**I get this error in my MSTest:**

```
    System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Error in line 1 position 70. Expecting element 'InventoryResponse' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Responses'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 

'Fault', namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/envelope/none'. 
    at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.ReadObject(XmlReader reader)
```

Also which is weird is it's talking about the xml reader above.  I specified json as the content type so why is it trying to parse with xml?

*Side note:* When I try a POST in Fiddler to the same uri and specify a json representation of InventoryRequest in the fiddler body it works fine...and comes back with json

Comment: Try to find out the issue on the server. Here is instructions: http://philmunro.wordpress.com/2012/04/30/error-handling-strategies-part-1-wcf-services/ , http://johannblais.blogspot.com/2009/02/handling-exceptions-right-way-in-wcf.html

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    inventoryResponse = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("Inventory", inventoryRequest).Result.Content.ReadAsAsync<InventoryResponse>();
}
```